# Different objects having the same reference to a member and debugger values are different from output

Tags: java, debugging

I have run into this weird issue where 3 different instances of objects have a member variable with the same reference(they basically have the same values when they shouldn't). The problem I'm trying to solve is the 8-puzzle game using state space representation and the A* search in Java.

I have three classes, `Node`, `BoardState` and `GameSolver` and are declared as such :

```
public class BoardState {

private int[][] goalState = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 0}};
private int[][] board;
private int spaceRow, spaceCol;}

public class Node {
public BoardState state;
public Node parentNode;
private int cost;}

public class GameSolver {
private List<Node> expandedList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Node> unexpandedList = new ArrayList<>();
private Node initialState;}
```

My problem appears when I try to create a list of unexpanded nodes inside the search. I use this method:

```
public List<BoardState> possibleMoves()
{
    List<BoardState> moves = new ArrayList<>();

    if(isValidMove(this.spaceRow, this.spaceCol + 1))
        moves.add(moveRight());
    if(isValidMove(this.spaceRow, this.spaceCol - 1))
        moves.add(moveLeft());
    if(isValidMove(this.spaceRow - 1, this.spaceCol))
        moves.add(moveUp());
    if(isValidMove(this.spaceRow + 1, this.spaceCol))
        moves.add(moveDown());

    return moves;
}
```

and this is how a move looks like:

```
    public BoardState moveRight()
{

    int[][] newBoard = this.getBoard();
    BoardState newState = new BoardState(newBoard);
    int aux = newState.board[spaceRow][spaceCol];
    newState.board[spaceRow][spaceCol] = newState.board[spaceRow][spaceCol + 1]; //swap values between them
    newState.board[spaceRow][spaceCol + 1] = aux;
    newState.setPos(spaceRow, spaceCol + 1);
    return newState;
}
```

In the initial state I have chosen, the only 2 available moves are left or up so inside the method that does the search, it successfully creates a new list of children nodes with the correct blank space positions but the matrix representing tiles have the same reference and value as the parent node (in my case `n`) even though I modify them in the `moveX` method.

Here is the method for the A* search:

```
    public List<BoardState> solve()
{
    unexpandedList.add(initialState); //add root node
    while(unexpandedList.size() != 0)
    {
        Node n = getOptimalF(unexpandedList);  //get the node with the least f value
        expandedList.add(n); //add current node to expanded list
        unexpandedList.remove(n); //remove it from the unexpanded list
        if(n.state.isGoal())
        {
            List<BoardState> path = new ArrayList<>();

            Node currentNode = n;

            while(currentNode.parentNode != null) //if solution was found, backtrack steps
            {
                path.add(currentNode.state);
                currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
            }

            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            List<BoardState> moveList = n.state.possibleMoves(); //get list of possible successors
            for(BoardState b : moveList)
            {
                if(Node.alreadyExpanded(b,expandedList) != null)
                    continue;
                int g = n.getCost() + 1;

                Node successor = Node.alreadyExpanded(b,unexpandedList);

                if(successor == null) //if node is present in the unexpanded list and has a lower
                    continue;         //g value add it as a successor
                if(successor.getCost() > g)
                    continue;
                unexpandedList.add(new Node(successor.state.clone(), n, g));
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have also tried testing if the methods that move the blank space(in my case it's the integer 0) work and created 2 states as such :

```
    BoardState test = new BoardState(board);
    test.printBoard();
    System.out.println();
    BoardState test2 = test.moveLeft();
    test2.printBoard();
    test.printBoard();
```

While executing normally, the first 2 outputted matrices are correct, but the 3rd has the same values as the 2nd and the debugger shows me weird values for example the last row should look like `2 0 1` but instead I get `2 0 0` in the debugger.

I am thinking that I haven't done the deep copy properly somewhere, but I don't know where.

[Here's](https://github.com/Ascerte/A-search-solving-the-8-Puzzle-Game) a github link to the full code just in case:

Comment: `int[][] newBoard = this.getBoard();
    BoardState newState = new BoardState(newBoard);`. According to the code on github, nether the getter nor the constructr creates a deep copy of the array.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot, that solved my issue.

Comment: @TanasaSilviu link from the question is not working.